# Why would WaitForSingleObject return WAIT_FAILED

Tags: windows, winapi, mutex

MSDN says

> If the function fails, the return value is WAIT_FAILED.  To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

The code is:

```
HANDLE     m_mutex_handle;    /**< m_mutex_handle. The handle to the created mutex. */
m_mutex_handle = ::CreateMutex( 0, false, NULL );
::WaitForSingleObject( m_mutex_handle, INFINITE );
```

But what are the reasons that could happen?

Comment: So, what does GetLastError() return? That usually gives you a pretty good clue.

Answer (score 7):

If you lack the SYNCHRONIZE privilege on the object, then you cannot wait. WAIT_FAILED will be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Passing in a bogus object might cause that.

Comment: Passing in a _seriously_ bogus object may even cause undefined behaviour, but perhaps the function checks for those cases. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Closing a handle while the handle is being waited on can also cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I got WAIT_FAILED from WaitForMultipleObjects when passing in an array of thread handles as one of them was a pseudo handle. As ever the immortal Raymond Chen explained, and provided the fix: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141015-00/?p=43843

Comment: If you are looking at this question you should read Raymond Chen's blog post linked above. Basically not all handles are handles some are special placeholder 'psuedo handles' and are not absolute values.