# Failure in synchronization APIs for C++ code under Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization

If I define a template struct like so:

```
template <typename T> 
struct SYNCHED_DATA
{
    SYNCHED_DATA()
    {
        hMutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    }
    ~SYNCHED_DATA()
    {
        if(hMutex)
            CloseHandle(hMutex);
        hMutex = NULL;
    }

    void set(T* pV)
    {
        if(pV)
        {
            ::WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            var = *pV;
            ::ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
    }
    void get(T* pV)
    {
        if(pV)
        {
            ::WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
            *pV = var;
            ::ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        }
    }

private:
    HANDLE hMutex;
    T var;

    SYNCHED_DATA(const SYNCHED_DATA& s)
    {
    }
    SYNCHED_DATA& operator = (const SYNCHED_DATA& s)
    {
    }
};
```

Can I be assured that those WaitForSingleObject() APIs will always return WAIT_OBJECT_0? And if no, in what circumstances can they fail and how am I supposed to handle it then?

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) goes into detail on the return codes.

Comment: "WAIT_FAILED = The function has failed. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." -- you can it "into detail"???

Comment: I meant it has all of the possible return values and what they mean. In case you haven't noticed, the errors list in use by `GetLastError()` is gigantic as well.

Comment: So what, I need a "gigantic" switch statement for all of them?

Comment: If you find yourself getting one of those, it's generally best to display/log the error code and optionally use `FormatMessage` to convert it to a string describing the error.

Comment: Yes, from a user-mode code. But this is a template struct that can be used in a device driver or in a local service app that all use different logging techniques. Again, the question here is not how to process WinAPI errors, but whether an error is even possible in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Old New Thing has an article on how closing the handle before the wait succeeded will result in `WAIT_ABANDONED` for anybody waiting:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/12/463977.aspx

There is some discussion of `WAIT_FAILED` on this very site:

[Why would WaitForSingleObject return WAIT_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210751/why-would-waitforsingleobject-return-wait-failed)

These suggest that failure is a possibility even with an infinite timeout.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can a handle be closed before the wait succeeds in the code I posted above? Maybe I'm just not seeing something...

Comment: One thread runs `get`, say, gets the mutex, and starts on the copy. (Let's say you have `SYNCHED_DATA<std::vector<std::string> >`, or something, with lots of strings in it.) 1+ other thread(s) simultaneously attempt to get the mutex, and end up waiting. Then another thread destroys the SYNCHED_DATA object while this is going on. This is a bit contrived but I don't think enough information is provided to prove that this can't happen.

Comment: OK, one possibility would be if a thread is terminated while it owns the mutex. But I don't even use TerminateThread API in my code.

Comment: You will have to figure out whether this information is relevant to your code overall or not; I think it is certainly relevant to the snippet provided in the question, which is given without context.