# Boost: Assertion on thread interruption

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I get the following assertion, when I try to interrupt a thread, which is waiting on a condition variable:

```
unsigned const retval(win32::WaitForSingleObject(sem, ::boost::detail::win32::infinite));
BOOST_VERIFY( 0 == retval || ::boost::detail::win32::wait_abandoned == retvalfile );

...\boost\thread\win32\basic_timed_mutex.hpp, line 85
```

Apparently the previous code returns WAIT_FAILED - is this behavior of boost correct, or something is wrong with my code?

If I also consider WAIT_FAILED in the check, everything runs smoothly. I have also found a similar bug on [boost trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8422).

Comment: Have a read of this link then single step your code to check that you are actually waiting on a valid object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210751/why-would-waitforsingleobject-return-wait-failed