# Windows callback WaitForSingleObject() SYNCHRONIZE privilege

Tags: windows, winapi, callback, synchronization

I have a callback:

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback(
  LPVOID pvParam,
  PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams
)
{...}
```

as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nc-bluetoothapis-pfn_authentication_callback_ex

Before I can unregister that callback using the `BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication()` function
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothunregisterauthentication),
I call the `WaitForSingleObject()` function.
I pass to this function the `HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION` callback handle.

`WaitForSingleObject()` returns `WAIT_FAILED`.
And `GetLastError()` returns the code 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`).

I read on Stackoverflow, in another thread,
([Why would WaitForSingleObject return WAIT_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210751/why-would-waitforsingleobject-return-wait-failed)):

> "If you lack the SYNCHRONIZE privilege on the object, then you cannot
>   wait. WAIT_FAILED will be returned."

So here is my question:

How can I check that?

If the object is the callback handle, how can I check that it has the `SYNCHRONIZE` privilege?

Shall I use the following function:

```
#include <AclAPI.H>
GetSecurityInfo()
```

How should I invoke it?

I have tried:

```
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = 0;
DWORD dwReturnCode = 0;
dwReturnCode = GetSecurityInfo(handle, SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE, SYNCHRONIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0, &psd);
```

It returns code 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

Thanks for your help.

---

### Edit 1

Indeed, in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedeviceex, 
there is that sentence:

> Use an infinite timeout since the handle to the function that sets the
>   event is being deleted.

I have to say that, when I read it, I didn't understand it. Let's be honest: I still do not really understand it. What is this "event" that pops up suddenly in the documentation? Ok. So you may think that I am dumb or unprofessional. I am just not a Windows specialist and this is respectable.

I have to say that this `bluetoothapis.h` API really lacks practical code samples. I think the one I mentioned is the only one.

Note for Microsoft - If Microsoft wants "people" to use its APIs, Microsoft should to give them a little bit more than just five lines of code and not always understandable explanations (at least for non-super-specialists).
Didn't they abandon Windows Mobile because they didn't have enough developers to program applications for their devices?
Yes, well maybe also for obscure financial reasons and "strategical choices" that do not take developers and companies into account, but the reason for abandoning Windows Mobile I just mentioned, is one reason they give. I used to program for Windows Mobile. Now, I have to program using Windows APIs on the one side and Android/Java code on the other side. Pardon me if I am not a specialist of either one.

So, for me, `BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx()` and `BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication()` are black boxes and eventually the callback is executed.

I don't see what to do with the code in the link you provide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-event-objects). I don't see how to integrate the callback in it.

I have a callback defined as a free function with this prototype:

```
BOOL CALLBACK BluetoothAuthCallback(LPVOID pvParam, PBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_CALLBACK_PARAMS pAuthCallbackParams)
```

and I use the black boxes mentioned above to register and unregister the callback.

Can you please show me, with some code (or pseudo-code), what is to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` because `HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION` callback handle - not a handle to kernel object.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure this is what you meant but I changed SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE to SE_KERNEL_OBJECT in the GetSecurityInfo() call. Now, GetSecurityInfo() returns 6...

Comment: all what you try todo is wrong. `HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION` is not kernel object, so you can not use it with `WaitForSingleObject` or `GetSecurityInfo`. then system clear say to - handle is **invalid** but not access denied. so you go in absolute false direction. as general note (unrelated to your case) - `SYNCHRONIZE` this is not privilege but access right (this is absolute different things)

Comment: also as general note `GetSecurityInfo` - get security decsriptor of object. this is absolute unrelated to kernel object handle granted access, with which it was created. so even if you will be have some kernel object handle - get or set object security descriptor is senseless (not affect handle granted access). but you even not have handle at all. and your error not in access denied on handle but in - you have not handle

Comment: A handle is a reference to an object or record. Some handles are pointers that reference an object or record directly in user space, such as `HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION`. OTOH, often a handle value is an index into a table of handle entries. At a minimum, an entry associates a handle value with an object or record, which may be in kernel space or the user space of another process. An entry may have additional state. For example, a handle entry for a kernel object has flags such as whether the handle can be closed, and it has the access mask of granted rights.

Comment: Why are you waiting on the `HBLUETOOTH_AUTHENTICATION_REGISTRATION` anyway? What are you actually trying to wait for? Are you trying to wait for the registration to become unregistered? (But you are the one doing the unregistering, so you don't need to wait. You are already in control.)

Comment: @LéaMassiot First, the callback handle is not supported by `WaitForSingleObject` function for waiting for. Refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) for which object can be wait by `WaitForSingleObject`. Second, the callback is used to receive authentication events. When you don't need monitor these authentication events any more, call `BluetoothUnregisterAuthentication` to remove the callback. That's all. For your use case described in your question, it doesn't require or need to call `WaitForSingleObject`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the explanations. Since I posted my initial question, I re-found the code sample that is related to my issue. Here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedeviceex. This is the reason why I am using the WaitForSingleObject() function. Now that I think about it, maybe it is normal I get the error code number 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) for the WaitForSingleObject() function because, as far as I understand the code, this function is waiting for the callback to be destroyed.

Comment: @LéaMassiot No, callback handle can't be used in `WaitForSingleObject`. The [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedeviceex) you refer to doesn't show complete code. The `hEvent` can be created via [`CreateEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function and set to signaled via [`SetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent) at the end of callback function.

Comment: @LéaMassiot So when `WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, INFINITE)` return with [`WAIT_OBJECT_0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) value indicate the callback function return. That's the purpose. The event used here is for synchronizing multiple threads. Refer to [Using Event Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-event-objects) for a complete example.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT I edited my initial post (cf. EDIT 1). Thank you.

Comment: @LéaMassiot For code sample issue you reported I've submitted internally.